# Why is 'player' returning nil?

Tags: lua, roblox

It keeps returning nil for player and saying that im trying to index a nil with 'WaitForChild' even though I have tried adding a wait command and changing player to 'game.Players.LocalPlayer' I'm new to scripting and I don't know what else to do.

```
local buyButton = script.Parent
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local multiplier = player:WaitForChild("Multiplier")

buyButton.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
    if multiplier.Value == 0 then
        multiplier.Value = 1
    end
end)
```

Comment: If this is a server script, `.LocalPlayer` will return nil

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer` you want to do:

```lua
   local players = game:GetService("Players")
   local player = players.localplayer
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is functionally equivalent to their line, except your capitalization is incorrect for LocalPlayer